# Button not going to another view when clicked in Grails

Tags: java, grails

I have this Cancel button and when I am pressing it, it is not going to required view page. Whats the error? It is not showing any action. I don't want to change the `button` to `g:submitbutton` because my CSS will change so I want to cancel this operation using button tag. I am using Grails.

mains.gsp

```
<button type="button" onclick="${remoteFunction(action:'index', controller: 'organization')}"  class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: What version of Grails?

Answer (score 0):

`remoteFunction` has been deprecated since at least grails 2.5?  Regardless (unless I'm remembering poorly), it's an AJAX function that returns the result of the URL as data that you can use to update elements on the page with JavaScript.  You would need to tell it what to do with that data on the cancel.

If you're trying to send them to a different page with the button, then I'd just use a styled `<g:link/>` instead of worrying about a remote function.  But maybe you're trying to do something else with the results?